# ws xml-rpc, processing custom xml on server

Tags: java, xml-rpc

i need to build an xml-rpc server using apache ws java implementation for processing some requests like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<Method>Ping</Method>
<AuthToken>dfgFGt5gefgv4EDFG</AuthToken>
<Params></Params>
<TS>1360905157</TS>
<Hash>d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249</Hash>
</Root>
```

Does anyone know how to override  `<methodName></methodName>` by `<Method></Method>` in the server implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your protocol differs from the standard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC and ws-xmlrpc is not configurable in such way.

Anyway, if you are such willing to hack it, export ws-xmlrpc from repository (at this moment is <strike>pi-SNAPSHOT</strike> 3.1.4-SNAPSHOT):

`svn export https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/xmlrpc/trunk xmlrpc`

edit `common/src/main/java/org/apache/xmlrpc/parser/XmlRpcRequestParser.java`

```
line 77: "methodCall" => "Root"
line 85: "methodName" => "Method"
line 93: "params" => "Params"
```

Compile with maven to install to local repo:

`mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

And sing a prayer to FSM, because most surely will not work.

Can't you change your client? :P

P.S.: Code not tested.